# Duplicate Virtual Object in Tango AR Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Can someone tell me why this is happen? i follow the tutorial from Tango AR to place virtual object in Augmented Reality. After i place the object, the camera freeze and the kitten got duplicate when i move the smartphone. I'm using Unity 5.6.2 and for Lenovo for Tango.

Below are the sample image from my android device.

[image: Duplicate Kitten]

Comment: It is not duplicated object. Basically, tango camera just stops working for some reason. I suggest make a development build, open Android Studio and take a look at logs to see what's wrong.

Comment: got no error on logcat.. everything just fine until i place kitten by touch on surface. and suddenly like the image i shared.. if i minimize the application and go back, sometimes it will do just fine and nothing error. but on the first time always get stuck like that

Comment: So if I understand you correctly there are no errors even after you place an object and the camera got frozen, right? In that case could you share some code?

Comment: yes. Everything just fine. when i add the object, the camera got frozen. 
This is the code to add kitten. Same with the tutorial.

https://pastebin.com/TuEFDwwb

Comment: Yes, it looks fine. I'm giving up. If you want you can zip you project and share a link I will take a look.

Comment: This is the zip version of my project. Really appreciated if you want to look it.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qXfYqbEs6tJx3xfxKWf6XTcSrrdeMVbk

when i minimize and go back, the camera will do fine. maybe you can tell me how to simulate pause on tango without close and reopen the apps. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the camera clear flags from depth to solid color and it should be ok

Comment: yep, that's it.

Comment: no problem, I had the same issue 2 weeks ago when I switched to the last version of the sdk, I don't remember how I figured it out, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off shadows on your light.  That way you can keep the clear flags set to depth.